# Popup z-order and YouTube videos

Tags: bug, status-completed

If you click on a link that opens an action popup, it opens behind videos. I don't know if this would happen with anything else than videos though.

I'm using Chrome.

This is the example question I used in the following screenshot: [How can I beat level 3-15 in Angry Birds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-can-i-beat-level-3-15-in-angry-birds/3749#3749)

[image]

Comment: Interesting. The popup is behind the video, but in front of a tag info popup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80678/tag-info-tooltip-displayed-behind-proposed-edit-window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused by subtlety around embedding Flash objects into a page, but it will be fixed on the next deployment.

The generated HTML has changed, so older posts will continue to exhibit this until they are edited (a proper post body change).

Comment: I remember having this problem, mainly with IE. I feel your pain.